# Is there way I can lazy load an accordion pane's datasource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to lazy load the content datasource of an accordion pane. So in other words, when the pane is opened, it will bind the datasource. I'm unable to find an event that I can use to fire the `if (source == null) LoadMe();` logic.

I know at least a hundred people out there have done this before. Any ideas would be helpful. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got it working. Im not entirely happy with it, but this is what I got:

Each header has a link button that I sized to fill the entire area, essentially making that area clickable:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID="acpInReview" runat="server">
    <Header>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Width="100%" Height="25" CssClass="SectionLinkButtons" CommandName="LoadInReview">In Review</asp:LinkButton>
    </Header>
```

As you see, it has an associated command with it. in the parent accordion, I set the event handler that fires when a command is detected within the template:

```
<ajaxToolkit:Accordion runat="server" ID="accMainNav" HeaderCssClass="AccordionSection"
                       CssClass="AccordionMainNav" ContentCssClass="AccordionContent"
                       RequireOpenedPane="False" SelectedIndex="-1"
                       OnItemCommand="accMainNav_OnItemCommand" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <Panes>
        ...
```

Then in the code behind, the handler reads the command and does it's thing:

```
protected void accMainNav_OnItemCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.CommandName)
    {
        case "LoadAwaitingControllerApproval":
            LoadAwaitingControllerApproval();
            break;
        case "LoadInReview":
            LoadInReview();
            break;
        case "LoadAwaitingFinalization":
            LoadAwaitingFinalization();
            break;
    }
}
```

I also wrapped the whole thing in an updatepanel so that i could use the updateprogress control. So essentially what happens is the link button gets clicked when you click on a header which fires a command. That command is routed to the event handler which binds the datasource. Since it is in an updatepanel, it happens asynchronously and I use the updateprogress control to display a loading indicator. I could improve it by backing the link button with a div that covers the whole area then give that div an onclick event that causes a postback. But for now, this works.